# Docker container crashes - problematic managing container after that

Tags: docker, go, containers

I run:

- docker: Docker version 17.03.0-ce, build 60ccb22
- linux: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Image inside docker container runs some golang app, which (I found this know) wasn't properly dealing with errors. I should include os.Exit(1) for cases like mine, for error checking.

I run/start docker container with command like

`docker run -it --restart=always --env-file ~/PRODUCTION/services/resolvment_api/.environmet_variables -p 8081:3003 --name resolvment_2 -d resolvment-api`

Ok, then it looks like an error occur inside a docker container on app level. At this point something strange happens to docker/docker container.

If i do `docker ps` I can see

`2e7b02258647        resolvment-api   "/bin/sh -c $GOBIN..."   9 days ago          Up 37 hours         0.0.0.0:8081->3003/tcp   resolvment_2`

1. I can do `docker logs 2e7b02258647` and will see logs.
2. If I try to do `docker stop 2e7b02258647` I get container id in next line as usually when you successfully stop a container. Then if i do `docker ps` again... I can still see docker container (with same id) listed there?!
3. If I then try to forcefully remove the container with `docker rm -f 2e7b02258647` I get an error 
   `Error response from daemon: Unable to remove filesystem for 2e7b02258647ec357fd1beb0083ad678eb381474f1315b3e524d318472c5f061: remove /var/lib/docker/containers/2e7b02258647ec357fd1beb0083ad678eb381474f1315b3e524d318472c5f061/shm: device or resource busy`
    but docker container is not listed anymore under `docker ps`.
4. Then I want to add/start again the container with command `docker run -it --restart=always --env-file ~/PRODUCTION/services/resolvment_api/.enviroment_variables -p 8081:3003 --name resolvment_2 -d resolvment-api`

and the error that i get as response is this: `fc174f65cc34a2573563729acfe11436370ab08965be553e682d82e7af06b236
docker: Error response from daemon: service endpoint with name resolvment_2 already exists.`

so i do `docker rm resolvment_2`, and try to start again... but same error.

if i put -f with rm command... doesn't help either.

So, rm/run/rm/run.... walking in circle... doesn't help.

And I can't just restart docker daemon, since there are few other containers running.

Would really aprechiate some help on this.

Best,
Tomaz

Comment: Have experience something similar once and it turned out that some process outside docker had a lock on a volume file and didn't allow removing the container. So had to kill that process. Run `sudo lsof | grep docker` and see if you can find any process causing issue

Comment: try to bash into the container and kill any weird process, you can check for strange things with `stats`or `top`. After that try again the `rm -f` command.